# Vertically center content with BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm trying to center the content of a JPanel with BoxLayout vertically. The BoxLayout is aligned to the Y-axis, so items inside are aligned horizontally.

For example, what I have now:

```
-----------------------------
|          ------           |
|        ----------         |
|           ----            |
|      --------------       |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

What I want:

```
-----------------------------
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|          ------           |
|        ----------         |
|           ----            |
|      --------------       |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

At the moment, I'm centering the column of elements using setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT):

```
JPanel box = new JPanel();
box.setLayout(new BoxLayout(box, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JLabel one = new JLabel("First element");
one.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
box.add(one);
JLabel two = new JLabel("Second element");
two.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
box.add(two);
...
```

How could I change this to also be vertically centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BoxLayout` layout allows components to grow (up to their maximum size) when extra space is available.

You need to add components that are allowed to grow. The basic code would be:

```
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
box.add(...);
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
```

The two "glue" components on the top/bottom will grow to fill available space.